# Scrapy: select texts of all children elements but returns children HTML as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am writing a Scrapy spider to scrape [this page](https://itch.io/jam/cyberpunk-jam), I only want the text of the element with class `jam_content` and all its descendants. So ideally I should get

```
CYBERPUNK GAME JAM 2014
CLICK HERE!
```

This is my selector `response.css(".jam_content *::text").extract()` :

which returns even the HTML of the children

```
['\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 '\r\n',
 'CYBERPUNK GAME JAM 2014',
 '\r\n',
 '\r\n  \r\n  .game_grid .game_cell .game_title a {\r\n    color: #029671;\r\n  }\r\n  \r\n    .game_grid .game_cell .game_author a {\r\n    color: #00aa99;\r\n  }\r\n  \r\n    .game_grid .game_cell .game_genre {\r\n    color: #c5007d;\r\n  }\r\n  \r\n      .game_grid .game_cell .game_platform {\r\n    color: #990088;\r\n  }\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  .add_game_btn {\r\n    background-color: #029671;\r\n    border: 4px solid #c5007d;\r\n    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #380024;\r\n    padding: 10px 15px;\r\n    font-size: 18px;\r\n    font-family: \'Lucida Console\';\r\n    color: #00ffcc;\r\n    cursor: pointer;\r\n} \r\n  \r\n
.view_jam .grid_outer {\r\n    border-top:0;\r\n    border-bottom:0;\r\n    background:#000; }\r\n  \r\nbody {\r\n\tbackground-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ReRqo6t.png);\r\n\tbackground-repeat: repeat-x;\r\n\tbackground-color: #000;\r\n}\r\nbody,td,th {\r\n\tcolor: #0FF;\r\n\tfont-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;\r\n}\r\na:link {\r\n\tcolor: #C5007D;\r\n}\r\na:visited {\r\n\tcolor: #C5007D;\r\n}\r\na:hover {\r\n\tcolor: #C5007D;\r\n}\r\na:active {\r\n\tcolor: #C5007D;\r\n}\r\n.mag_not_link {\r\n\tcolor: #C5007D;\r\n\tfont-weight: bold;\r\n}\r\n',
 '\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n',
 '\r\n  ',
 '\r\n  ',
 'CLICK HERE!',
 '\r\n',
 '\r\n\r\n']
```

I attempted another one `response.xpath("./*[@class='jam_content']//text()")`, which returns nothing

How do I do this?

Comment: try `response.css(".jam_content *::text").get_all()`

Comment: @maestro.inc I got `AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'get_all'`.

Comment: apologies, that was a typo, i meant `response.css(".jam_content *::text").get()`

Comment: @maestro.inc It returns `'\r\n\r\n\r\n'`. This seems like the first element of the output I got before. You could try on your side with a simple spider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your selector to not get the contents of the `style` element:

```
response.css(".jam_content *:not(style)::text").extract()
```

You could then do a list comprehension, filtering out the items that are blank text with `.strip()`:

```
my_text = [text for text in response.css(".jam_content *:not(style)::text").extract() if text.strip()]
```

This will return:

```
['CYBERPUNK GAME JAM 2014', 'CLICK HERE!']
```

Then you can simply join it together:

```
print('\n'.join(my_text))
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a more general way to filter out all inner HTML? This is because I scrape many similar pages, and I am not sure what other elements are inside.

Comment: It depends. If you have to remove some inner html that has tags, you can use: `from w3lib.html import remove_tags`